# is there a way to show elapsed time of an in-process request in postman?

Tags: rest, api, postman

Is there a way to show current elapsed time of an in-process request in Postman? I think Postman displays the elapsed time after an API request has completed but is there a way to show the elapsed time of an API call which is currently in process in Postman?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that through the native client (might be wrong). Could you wrap the request in a newman script and use some of these events github.com/postmanlabs/newman#newmanrunevents to create your own elapsed time tool/output?